# Неправильный синтаксис скрипта

Tags: jquery

Помогите пожалуйста исправить, в консоли ошибка

```
$('input').parent().on('click', function () {
  var $slider = $(this).find('input');
  $slider.update({"disable": false});
  alert('The slider was clicked!');
});
```

Comment: какая ошибка в консоли?

Comment: (index):37 Uncaught TypeError: $slider.update is not a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы хотите сделать инпут неактивным, то надо написать так

```
 var $slider = $(this).find('input');
 $slider.prop( "disabled", true );
```

обратно активным его сделать можно вот так

```
 $slider.prop( "disabled", false );
```

Comment: Мне нужно чтоб был активным при нажатии

Comment: $slider.prop( "disabled", false );

Comment: не получается. применить к слайдеру, он игнорирует

Comment: к этому http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/

Comment: Переформулируйте вопрос, чтобы стало понятно, что у вас происходит, и  что вы хотите получить

Comment: ладно, как изначально применить к элементу disabled, а при клике на него снять disabled

Comment: я показал, как. но вы, видимо, хотите сделать неактивным весь ваш слайдер? это выходит за рамки изначального вопроса  - рекомендую почитать документацию к плагину слайдера. возможно, что сделать его disable никак и нельзя.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/v9ofnqhs/

Comment: а в исходном коде нет disabled